# Cloning SSD with dd But Clone Does Not Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd, dd

At my job we have always used `dd` to make clones of our master OS image, but recently we have updated from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04. We made an image of it and created a news SSD with it.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/masterSSD of=/dev/newSSD bs=4096
```

When we place the new SSD into a computer other than the one the master was originally installed on it won't boot. However, when we place the new SSD into the computer that the master was originally installed on it boots.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the new partition is flagged bootable?

Comment: Is the SSD the only drive in the computers? Are SATA ports identical?

Comment: @Takkat There are no sata ports. It is an Intel Nuc.

Comment: @cargo how do I check if it is marked bootable?

Comment: @Austin Barrett `fdisk -l` will list all the partitions, a * will mark the partition flagged bootable.  that should be on the partition that the system looks for the boot loader on

Answer (score 1):

and thanks for the help. After some more searching between my coworkers and I, we found a solution here:

[UEFI boot fails when cloning image to new machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380447/uefi-boot-fails-when-cloning-image-to-new-machine)

Thanks to @RodSmith for the answer.

Regards,
Austin